# Why am I having error messages whenever I try to import tensorflow?

Tags: windows, tensorflow, python-3.8

I use Windows 10 and have installed tensorflow (including tensorflow-gpu) successfully. But when I try to `import tensorflow as tf`I get the following error:

```
    ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-64156d691fe5> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     39 
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     41 
     42 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in <module>
     33 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
     34 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2
---> 35 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
     36 from tensorflow.python import tf2
     37 from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py in <module>
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=invalid-import-order,g-bad-import-order, wildcard-import, unused-import
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     29 from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tfe import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 
     85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manzs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I read the suggestions in the tensorflow website, and none of them helped.

Is this a mapping issue in the Windows on my PC or do I need to upload a DLL?

Comment: What is your tensorflow version assuming that you are running python 3.8?

Answer (score 0):

The DLL issue comes because of improperly configured CUDA and CuDNN. Please check if you have set the environment variables correctly. Also, it can come if your TF version is not compatible with CUDA version you have.